# Windows 7: How do I find missing drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I installed windows 7 32 bit for a friend, his laptop is hp 2000-2d07ee. I installed all the drivers I could find [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=4062&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=5451237). I ran windows update, I searched in device manager for these drivers couldn't find them

[image]

I googled, found nothing, do you know how I can get them?

**Update**
These are the device IDs:

[image: device properties]

Comment: Are you actually missing functionality on your system? If not then you can just leave them.

Comment: Also did you do the "Scan Now" system scan on that page you linked to?

Comment: @JasonC it's not my pc, if my friend decides to connect his laptop to internet through ethernet, he wouldn't be able to. I don't use windows personally, it's not my pc, I'm a nixer. I can't predict what my friend is going to do with his laptop, I have to install all drivers for him. yes I did scan now, found nothing

Comment: No need to get defensive. Anyways is there anything in http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Wireless-Internet-Home-Networking/network-controller-driver-is-not-installed-and-wireless-is/td-p/1629341/page/26 that helps? What is the vendor and device ID of the troublesome hardware?

Comment: @JasonC thanks for the links, how to find the device ID?

Comment: In the device manager, right-click the device and choose properties. Go to the details tab, then choose "hardware ids" from the property dropdown (you might find other useful info there as well, by the way). The IDs usually have a lot of slashes and ampersands in them.

Comment: @JasonC here http://i.imgur.com/ThKzxI4.jpg I found many

Comment: Please don't use those flaky driver fixer tools... You will end up with spyware and more problems.

Comment: @RyanGriggs Ah! I was fooled by the domain name. Official drivers for the RTL8102E on HP machines are at http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&softwareitem=ob-75268-1 (I've updated the answer below as well). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many devices, if Windows can't find the drivers, you can find them by doing the following:

1. Open the Device Manager
2. Right-click on the troublesome device and choose Properties
3. Go to the Details tab
4. Choose "Hardware IDs" from the property drop down.

There you will see a lot of numbers, like this:

```
PCI\VEN_10EC&DEV_8136&...
```

The 4 digits after "VEN" are the vendor ID, and the 4 digits after "DEV" are the device ID. In this case, vendor is 10EC and device is 8136. If the ID starts with "PCI", then:

1. Go to http://www.pcidatabase.com/
2. In the "device search" search box, type the device ID then search (for this example, [8136 search results](http://www.pcidatabase.com/search.php?device_search_str=8136&device_search=Search)). You could search for the vendor instead if you prefer.
3. If more than one device is listed, find the one with the matching vendor ID (10EC for us). Click the [vendor name](http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=1697) on the right.
4. Find the device ID in that list. That's your device. The model number and name will be there.

In your case the device is a RealTek RTL8102E ethernet controller, so at least now you have a good thing to Google for.

So we Google for "[hp realtek rtl8102e driver](https://www.google.com/search?q=hp%20rtl8102e%20driver)" and take a quick look at the results. Through there, we find the [official download page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?cc=us&lc=en&softwareitem=ob-75268-1) for those drivers, and the drivers can be obtained there. Take care to download drivers only from official sources; I added "hp" to the search terms to see if HP had an official set (the original link I posted was to unofficial drivers, which carry a potential risk).

I don't know why Windows wasn't able to find this device, it's not an uncommon controller. However, this technique can often be used to locate drivers that Windows can't find.

If your hardware ID in device manager doesn't start with "PCI", you might not be able to find it on that web site. In that case, a good starting point is to Google for the entire device string (do them all if there is multiple, or just search for the longest common prefix).

This won't be possible for all devices, of course.

---

For your SM Bus Controller, we can start with a search of the generic device description itself, perhaps modified with the machine's vendor name.

In your case, let's take a look at "[sm bus controller driver hp](https://www.google.com/search?q=sm+bus+controller+driver+hp)" (Google actually autocompleted most of that for me, interestingly... pay attention to search suggestions, if it is a common problem then these can be a good hint).

From there I found [Driver for SM Bus Controller in Windows](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02535465&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) on the official HP site. This contains a set of instructions. Follow these, and see if they do the trick.

Comment: I grabbed the bus driver from ryan's answer, the ethernet driver that he included in his answer did not worked, nor yours but when I installed the ethernet driver that you included in your answer, hp support center told me that a driver is missing so I installed it! thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Fischer Huh; I wonder what driver it was actually looking for. Still, glad you ended up finding the driver you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/Drivers/m-p/3540133#M181757
Looks like the 64-bit downloads also contain 32-bit versions.