# Lenovo ThinkPad L52 - Wireless driver

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, thinkpad

I just formatted and installed Windows 7 on my [Lenovo ThinkPad L520](http://support.lenovo.com/il/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-l-series-laptops/thinkpad-l520) laptop, and its wireless isn't working.

I see this networking status on my desktop:

[image]

I installed [Realtek LAN Driver for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit) - ThinkPad L420, L421, L520](http://support.lenovo.com/il/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-l-series-laptops/thinkpad-l520/downloads/DS013710) but still the wireless isn't working.

What do I have to install to get it to work?

**Edit:**

This is the stare under `Device Manager` -

[image]

**Edit 2:**

My Network Controller device is  -

`Intel Wireless Link WiFi 1000`

Comment: That's the driver for your wired network card not your wireless card ...

Comment: So what I have to install for wireles card ?

Comment: [ThinkPad Wireless LAN (802.11b/g/n) for Windows 7 (32-bit, 64-bit) - ThinkPad](https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/7zw407ww.exe)

Comment: <shrug> Go and look at http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/ThinkPad-L-Series-laptops/ThinkPad-L520?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like : I tried it and it still same results as in the post .

Comment: @DavidPostill : please indicate what I have to install from there .

Comment: @URL87 I've no idea :/

Comment: @URL87 Is your wireless Hardware switch turned ON ? Do you see any missing drivers in Device Manager

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like : please view my edit in the post , seems something is missing there ?

Comment: @URL87 Find the device ID & vendor ID of Network Controller using the instructions from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/771827/windows-7-how-do-i-find-missing-drivers) & download drivers

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like : I did as in the instructions , I add my Network Cotroller Device to the post , so which driver I have to download now ?

Comment: @URL87 Install [this](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/downloads/eula/23491/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-and-Drivers-for-Windows-7-?httpDown=https%3A%2F%2Fdownloadmirror.intel.com%2F23491%2Feng%2FWireless_16.7.0_s64.exe)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like : works  . Many thanks :)

Comment: @URL87 $10 that would be :p